# include statement in iphone html file

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, server-side-includes

Is this possible?  Basically, I have HTML file A, which I want to include in HTML files B, C, D, and E.  All of them will be displayed within my iOS app.  No internet involved -- everything will be on the device.

Comment: I'd guess you could *concatenate* two HTML files, but having an `include` in any form would require the file to be interpreted in some language on the phone, which I guess won't happen.

Comment: it is certainly possible Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

actually its possible

here is how its done

tell me if i am wrong

first file test.html has following contents

```
<html><body><object type="text/html" data="test2.html">

  <p>if object inclusion faile this takes over</p>
   </object></body></html>
```

and test2.html has this code

```
<div>blah</div>
```

Try open it in firefox and it should display blah

if its IE then use this code in your test.html

```
<html><body>
<object classid="clsid:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13" data="test2.html">
 <p>if object inclusion faile this takes over</p>
</object>
</body></html>
```

hope this helps

you can also have simple IE detection check like this

```
<!--[if IE]>
<html><body>
<object classid="clsid:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13" data="test2.html">
 <p>if object inclusion faile this takes over</p>
</object>
</body></html>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
<!-- place your other code here -->
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: you can also use IFrame btw to do something like this

Comment: I got a blog post on this its located here http://jaspreetchahal.org/how-to-insert-html-file-into-another-html-file-without-internet-connection/

Comment: It works, sort of.  The css is currently not getting picked up, but I'll work on that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard or magic way, but you would have to do it yourself with some native code. It shouldn't be too hard.

For example, imagine some files like this:

*index.html*

```
<div id="content">
  <% include1.html %>
</div>
```

*include1.html*

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

You could write native code to load the `index.html` file, and search for these special tags, and replace those tags with the content in the named html file that is also on the device.  You can then pass the HTML as a string to a webview to load and display.